# OSX find to match whole filenames

Tags: regex, macos, find

I'm trying to search for whole word ending with .properties

So far this works:

```
find -E . -iregex '.*[:alnum:]+\.properties'
```

But I want to find only paths like

`/some/path/messages.properties`

and not

`/some/path/messages_en.properties`

The previous regex matches "en.properties" So, Im trying to say something like:

```
.*\/[:alnum:]+\.properties
```

That is, anything followed by slash then a word and then .properties but the slash part seems not to be working

Comment: the problem is [:alnum:], you need to use [[:alnum:]]+ `.+/[[:alnum:]]+\.properties` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with anchor `$` on RHS and `/` on LHS to ensure filename is always complete:

```
find -E . -iregex '.*/[[:alnum:]]+\.properties$'
```

Comment: what is RHS and LHS?

Comment: By RHS (right hand side) I meant end of string where by using `$` we avoid matching `messages.properties123`. By LHS (left had side) I meant part before `messages` where are are using `/`